# Добавление данных таблицы БД в миграции

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, миграция

Как создать миграцию, чтобы можно было ее применять сколько угодно раз (либо не через миграцию - поясните через что лучше тогда). Пробую так

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TestForNewStyle.Data;
using TestForNewStyle.Models;

namespace TestForNewStyle.Migrations
{
    public partial class InsertData : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Иванов Сергей");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Сидоров Олег");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Кли");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Ям");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Га");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Пет");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Кар");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "К");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Тка");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Пис");
            migrationBuilder.InsertData("Client", "Name", "Ми");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

но после `update-database` миграцию применить не получается (если можно как то сделать, чтобы я смог применить ее повторно - то напишите пожалуйста).

Comment: Я так понимаю, вам нужно наполнять БД данными. Ищите по терминам [Seed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3), [Seeding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через миграцию вряд ли получится, т.к. она в принципе выполняется один раз. Чтобы выполнить миграцию повторно её надо откатить.

Самый простой способ решить Вашу задачу в случае EF - создать необходимые экземпляры сущностей (моделей) и сохранить их в БД соответствующим образом.

Comment: а можно как то создать файл настройки, чтобы запускать данную команду через терминал? (например принцип работы компиляции препроцессора LESS в VS Code). Или через что можно реализовать такой функционал: Я ввел какую-то команду (пусть это будет даже CMD-команда и у меня в БД добавились записи, которые мне нужно...я так понимаю это лучше сделать еще одно приложение чисто для добавления данных?

Comment: Теоретически да. Можно.